# how to use same code for every input tag?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple fields and need to apply the following for every single input I get, how can I write it so that I don't need to keep writing the same statement for each input field? I believe is not the most efficient way of doing.

```
var namefield = document.getElementById("name");
var surnamefield = document.getElementById("surname");
var emailfield = document.getElementById("email");

namefield.onfocus = function(){
    if (namefield.value != "" ){
        namefield.value ="";
    }
};

namefield.onblur = function(){
    if (namefield.value == "" ){
        namefield.value = "Please insert your name";
    }
};
```

As result I should get "please insert your Name" if click on first input, "please insert your surname" if click on second output, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Step one, name your function so you can pass it as a reference,

Step two use querySelectorAll to get all elements at once, and loop through

Step three, use addEventListener, optional, but cleaner.

```
function inputOnfocus = {
    if (this.value != "" ){
        this.value ="";
    }
};
function inputOnBlur(){
    if (this.value == "" ){
        this.value = "Please insert your " + this.title; 
        // note, will need to set title for each input
        // also, look into the placeholder attribute.
    }
};

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#name, #surname, #email');
for (var i= 0; i < inputs.length;i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('focus',onInputFocus, false);
    inputs[i].addEventListener('blur',onInputBlur, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
var namefield = document.getElementById("name");
var surnamefield = document.getElementById("surname");
var emailfield = document.getElementById("email");
var inputArray = [namefield , surnamefield , emailfield ];

inputArray.forEach(function(element){
    element.onfocus = function(){
        if (element.value != "" ){
            element.value ="";
        }
    };

    element.onblur = function(){
        if (element.value == "" ){
            element.value = "Please insert your " + element.id;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can name your functions and set them by name. When an event is called the context is set to the current dom object. So inside of the onfocus event `this` equals your field, e.g. `namefield`. Finally because you use a semi-human-readable identifier you can use this as part of your placeholder string by concatenating the fields ID. This leaves you with

```
function resetValue() {
    if (this.value != "" ){
        this.value ="";
    }
}

function insertPlaceholder() {
    if (this.value == "" ){
        this.value = "Please insert your " + this.ID;
    }
}

var namefield = document.getElementById("name");
var surnamefield = document.getElementById("surname");
var emailfield = document.getElementById("email");

namefield.onfocus = resetValue;
namefield.onblur = insertPlaceholder;

surnamefield.onfocus = resetValue;
surnamefield.onblur = insertPlaceholder;

emailfield.onfocus = resetValue;
emailfield.onblur = insertPlaceholder;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all input elements into an array by using the below code 
`var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input")` 
`for(input in inputs){ /*process input here.......*/ }`

Comment: This doesnt address their concern of giving different fields different placeholders and causes the same two functions to be created three times each.

Comment: then use .forEach() function

Comment: create one function which will receive an input element and do all the processing and call that function with the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna to show like "please insert your Name", alternatively you can use [input.placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) to make it easy:

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="please insert your Name" /><br />
<input type="text" id="surname" placeholder="please insert your Surname" /><br />
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="please insert Email" /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

You can bind the events with all the input elements by getting elements by tag name and while attaching the event you can customize your error text as well.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
       inputs[i].addEventListener('focus', function(){ if (this.value != "" ){this.value ="";}}, false);
       inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', function(){if (this.value == "" ){ this.value = "Please insert your "+ this.id;}}, false);
   }
```

```html
<input id="name">
<input id="surname">
<input id="email">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function emptyPlaceholder(field){
    if (field.value != "" ){
        field.value ="";
    }

};

function setPlaceholder(field){
    if (field.value == "" ){
        field.value = "Please insert your " + field.name;
    }

};
```

Also add onFocus and onblur to your tags

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" onblur="setPlaceholder(this)" onfocus="emptyPlaceholder(this)"/>
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" onblur="setPlaceholder(this)" onfocus="emptyPlaceholder(this)"/>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" onblur="setPlaceholder(this)" onfocus="emptyPlaceholder(this)"/>
```